# How do I search traces by error message text in Datadog?

Tags: datadog

A task I often find myself wanting to do is narrow down error traces in Databog by a certain type of error. For example, the application I work on often returns 500 errors from various endpoints with the following error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "pgbouncer.internal.equipmentshare.com" (10.0.4.193), port 6432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

However, it is hard to get a good picture of what percentage of our errors have this message vs. other messages (without manually counting them). I would like to filter my Datadog search query by this error message text, and see only those errors over time, but I haven't been able to construct a working query.

The most obvious thing seems to be to use Datadog's built in query building functionality, and just add a filter based on the message in one of the 500 response:

[image: datadog filter UI]

However, this appears to add a filter that Datadog does not know how to handle, and it filters out all results, including the one I copied the filter from in the first place.

[image]

My guess was that maybe, since it is a large, multiline error message with several special characters, that they just weren't being escaped properly, so I tried various combinations of escapes, wild cards, etc. to no avail. I also tried other error-related search facets and none of them worked. I also tried adding that facet as a column to the trace table, but it just added an empty column with no error message even for traces that have it.

[image]

Is there any way to filter traces in Datadog by full or partial error message text?